# Suppose that $n \gt m \ge 3$. Prove that if $m$ does not divide $n$, then $D_m$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $D_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $n \gt m \ge 3$. Prove that if $m$ does not divide $n$, then $D_m$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of $D_n$.

I know that since isomorphisms preserve order, if there has to exist an isomorphism between $D_m$ and $D_n$, m has to divide n  other wise there would exist an element in $D_n$ that cannot be mapped to any element in $D_m$, but im not sure exactly how to show this.

Any input would be appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Lagrange's theorem if $D_m$ was isomorphic to a subgroup of $D_n$, $|D_m|=2m$ would need to divide $|D_n|=2n$.  Can you spot a contradiction with your hypothesis?